# NodeJs Passport isAuthenticated() returning false even after login

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm new to Angular.js and trying to build local authentication for a website. I have gone through various sources and [Authentication in Single Page Applications](https://vickev.com/#!/article/authentication-in-single-page-applications-node-js-passportjs-angularjs) was very helpful. When I tried build the same in my localhost my code went in to a loop.

`app.post('/login',.....)` is returning user in the response but after that while loading the admin page it is checking whether the user is logged in by calling  `app.get('/loggedin',... )` and `req.isAuthenticated()` is returning `false` even after login and it goes to a loop. I can't understand why this is happening please help me.

Server Side code

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

//==================================================================
// Define the strategy to be used by PassportJS
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    if (username === "admin" && password === "admin") // stupid example
      return done(null, {name: "admin"});

    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
  }
));

// Serialized and deserialized methods when got from session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

// Define a middleware function to be used for every secured routes
var auth = function(req, res, next){
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) 
    res.send(401);
  else
    next();
};
//==================================================================

// Start express application
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.cookieParser()); 
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'securedsession' }));
app.use(passport.initialize()); // Add passport initialization
app.use(passport.session());    // Add passport initialization
app.use(app.router);

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

//==================================================================
// routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

app.get('/users', auth, function(req, res){
  res.send([{name: "user1"}, {name: "user2"}]);
});
//==================================================================

//==================================================================
// route to test if the user is logged in or not
app.get('/loggedin', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : '0');
});

// route to log in
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.user);
});

// route to log out
app.post('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logOut();
  res.send(200);
});
//==================================================================

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Client Side Js file

```
'use strict';

/**********************************************************************
 * Angular Application
 **********************************************************************/
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource','ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    //================================================
    // Check if the user is connected
    //================================================
    var checkLoggedin = function($q, $timeout, $http, $location, $rootScope){
      // Initialize a new promise
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // Make an AJAX call to check if the user is logged in
      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/loggedin').success(function(user){
        // Authenticated
        if (user !== '0')
          $timeout(deferred.resolve, 0);

        // Not Authenticated
        else {
          $rootScope.message = 'You need to log in.';
          $timeout(function(){deferred.reject();}, 0);
          $location.url('/login');
        }
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    };
    //================================================

    //================================================
    // Add an interceptor for AJAX errors
    //================================================
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function($q, $location) {
      return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(
          // Success: just return the response
          function(response){
            return response;
          }, 
          // Error: check the error status to get only the 401
          function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401)
              $location.url('/login');
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
        );
      }
    });
    //================================================

    //================================================
    // Define all the routes
    //================================================
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
      })
      .when('/admin', {
        templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl',
        resolve: {
          loggedin: checkLoggedin
        }
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
    //================================================

  }) // end of config()
  .run(function($rootScope, $http){
    $rootScope.message = '';

    // Logout function is available in any pages
    $rootScope.logout = function(){
      $rootScope.message = 'Logged out.';
      $http.post('http://localhost:3000/logout');
    };
  });


/**********************************************************************
 * Login controller
 **********************************************************************/
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
  // This object will be filled by the form
  $scope.user = {};

  // Register the login() function
  $scope.login = function(){
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', {
      username: $scope.user.username,
      password: $scope.user.password,
    })
    .success(function(user){
      // No error: authentication OK
      $rootScope.message = 'Authentication successful!';
      $location.url('/admin');
    })
    .error(function(){
      // Error: authentication failed
      $rootScope.message = 'Authentication failed.';
      $location.url('/login');
    });
  };
});



/**********************************************************************
 * Admin controller
 **********************************************************************/
app.controller('AdminCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  // List of users got from the server
  $scope.users = [];

  // Fill the array to display it in the page
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/users').success(function(users){
    for (var i in users)
      $scope.users.push(users[i]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey! I'm facing same issue, have you found the root cause?

Comment: The example looks a bit odd to me, as I would expect the request to `/loggedin` to be signed somehow, at least with a `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`, otherwise I am not sure the request would contain any reference to your logged user.

Comment: quick thoughts:  
>> angular session != express session
>> when angular is calling '/isloggedin' it is sending it's request session to express app which is NOT authenticated
  
  
Adding logs and if you could share those would be helpful to know what is the req object, etc. then we could probably resolve this faster :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to allow cookies to be set in cross domain

In express

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

And in ajax setup

```
 xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
 }
```

You can find relevant answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687313/what-exactly-does-the-access-control-allow-credentials-header-do) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732131/passport-express4-not-getting-authenticated-when-using-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

I think rdegges has part of the idea since cookies and session variables are part of what makes the state management work.  I think that bodyParser is also required but I omitted it here.

I'm using Passport on my website (authenticating to a MongoDB users table) and here are excerpts from my code.

/server.js:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
...
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var initPassport = require('./passport/init');
initPassport(passport);
...
self.app.use(cookieParser());
self.app.use(expressSession({secret: 'MYSECRETISVERYSECRET', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
self.app.use(passport.initialize());
self.app.use(passport.session());
...
var routes = require('./routes/index')(passport);
self.app.use('/', routes);
```

/passport/init.js:

```
var login = require('./login');
var signup = require('./register');
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  // Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializing user: ');
    console.log(user);
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      console.log('deserializing user:', user);
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

  // Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and SignUp/Registration
  login(passport);
  signup(passport);
}
```

/routes/index.js:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
...
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
  // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
  // request and response objects
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

For what it's worth I'm not seeing your isValidated() function anywhere defined.

Answer (score 1):

Can be so many things.

1.) Order as in [PassportJS Facebook login isAuthenticated returns false even though authentication succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365816/passportjs-facebook-login-isauthenticated-returns-false-even-though-authenticati?rq=1) (order seems correct though in your case).

2.) No req.login() as in [Passport and Passport Local req.isAuthenticated always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963216/passport-and-passport-local-req-isauthenticated-always-returns-false)

In this case I opt for the latter but for a different reason than in that question. 
You have provided your own `LocalStrategy`. To make the user log in, you will have to call `req.login()` yourself. Just as if you would define your own custom callback, as described in the `passport` documentation: http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue by forgetting to add

```
request.login()
```

on

```
app.post('/login', 
    function(request, response, next) {
        console.log(request.session)
        passport.authenticate('login', 
        function(err, user, info) {
            if(!user){ response.send(info.message);}
            else{

                request.login(user, function(error) {
                    if (error) return next(error);
                    console.log("Request Login supossedly successful.");
                    return response.send('Login successful');
                });
                //response.send('Login successful');
            }

        })(request, response, next);
    }
);
```

also make sure you have the following [order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111571/passports-req-isauthenticated-always-returning-false-even-when-i-hardcode-done/41601714#41601714) for initialization

```
var session = require('express-session');

// required for passport session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secrettexthere',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  // using store session on MongoDB using express-session + connect
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: config.urlMongo,
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}));

// Init passport authentication 
app.use(passport.initialize());
// persistent login sessions 
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your browser keeping your session cookie around? It sounds to me as if your browser isn't holding onto your session cookie after login, which is why subsequent requests to `/loggedin` are failing.

Comment: Why wouldn't the browser keep the cookie? It's suppose to be its default behavior!

Comment: This can happen for many reasons: eg, when the cookie is set it's set with an expirey time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried solution suggested by JMeas to manually call session saving, but it didn't work

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/482

```
req.session.save(function() { successRedirect(); })
```

After some experiments, I just moved app.use(session({ ... })) at the top of all middleware calls and now req.isAuthenticated() works as expected. I presume, session setup should go as the first middleware or at least before setting cookies.

Broken call :

```
var app = express();

app.use(query.json());
app.use(query.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookies());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'card',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use('/', routes); // this is where I call passport.authenticate()
```

Fixed call :

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'card',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(query.json());
app.use(query.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookies());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', routes);
```