# passport's req.isAuthenticated always returning false, even when I hardcode done(null, true)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to get my Passport local strategy working.

I've got this middleware set up:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    //return done(null, user);
    if (username=='ben' && password=='benny'){
        console.log("Password correct");
        return done(null, true);
    }
    else
        return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect Login"});
}));
```

but then in here

```
app.use('/admin', adminIsLoggedIn, admin);

function adminIsLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

it always fails and redirects to the home page.

I can't figure out why this is happening? Why won't it authenticate?

In my console I can see that's `Password Correct` is printing. 
Why won't it work?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Could be due to the express-session middleware needed for passport. Fixed it by using middlewares in the following order: (Express 4)

```
var session = require('express-session');

// required for passport session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secrettexthere',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  // using store session on MongoDB using express-session + connect
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: config.urlMongo,
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}));

// Init passport authentication 
app.use(passport.initialize());
// persistent login sessions 
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Am also facing the same problem...but not able to get solution

Comment: i have already did what you said above..but still am facing the problem

Comment: my problem was that I was calling 'passport.use , serializeUser , deserializeUser' but I wasn't calling 'app.use(passport.initialize());' and 'app.use(passport.session());' before that

Comment: @user2988146: Nice catch, I did the same mistake but now it works!

Comment: I have same problem, @Nitin you save my day!  why the order is so important to ruin everything?

Comment: @chiahao order is important because passport.session() depends on session

Comment: my order is same, but stil; I'm facing same problem.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I have been waisting hours thinking I'm too stupid to make this work. I simply had to change the order as you proposed and suddenly everything worked.

Answer (score 18):

FOR NEWBIES

I was facing a similar problem, where my isAuthenticated() function would return false.I lost a lot of time, hope this answer saves yours.

Some Common problems to watch out for,

1. Middleware setup order (express-session > pass.initialize > pass.session ).
2. Serialize and Deserialize methods needs to pass user on the request.(For more info I've posted an answer on this link.. [Basics of Passport Session (expressjs)-why do we need to serialize and deserialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45381931/8229646) ) if  there's no user on request then isAuthenticated would return false.... and redirect to the PATH defined ......when false....
3. The **getUserById** or **findById** function defined in the model(user.js) needs to have a User.findById (and not User.findOne) function defined.(this function would load user on the request in every session)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I searched a lot but wasn't find any solution, finally you give me solution.

Comment: I was using findOne() in findById() and now I replaced it with find() and it's working fine. Why there was the issue with findOne()

Comment: I actually need to use findOne instead of findById because i'm trying to do a case-insensitve lookup of the user's email. According to the docs findById is just syntactic sugar over findOne. I don't think requiring findById ought to be part of the accepted solution.

Answer (score 16):

This could also be an issue with your client's POST/GET calls. I had this exact same issue but it turned out that I had to give `fetch` (which is what I was using) the option `credentials:'include'` like so:

```
fetch('/...', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  credentials: 'include',
  body: ...
  ...})
```

The reason is because fetch doesn't support passing down cookies, which is necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks Alex! You saved me a lot of time.
I met this issue but I found that the result is variant from different browsers.
So I am sure this is the fetch compatibility issue!

Comment: Thanks Alex, if using axios. One might need to add  { withCredentials: true } instead

Comment: Thanks!!! if using express you must also in the cors middleware to include the origin and set credentials to true otherwise you will receive an error

Answer (score 14):

My problem was that i set cookie.secure to true even if data was not over https.

```
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: process.env.sessionSecret,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
    },
    store: store,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false } // Remember to set this
}));
```

Remember to set cookies to false if you're not using https

```
cookie: { secure: false } // Set to false
```

Also if you do believe you have https remember to trust the proxy

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
```

Comment: This worked for me.
To add something: it is not necessary to set `cookie: { secure: false }` since that is the default value.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue by forgetting to add

```
request.login()
```

on

```
app.post('/login', 
    function(request, response, next) {
        console.log(request.session)
        passport.authenticate('login', 
        function(err, user, info) {
            if(!user){ response.send(info.message);}
            else{

                request.login(user, function(error) {
                    if (error) return next(error);
                    console.log("Request Login supossedly successful.");
                    return response.send('Login successful');
                });
                //response.send('Login successful');
            }

        })(request, response, next);
    }
);
```

Hopefully that might help for others that ended up here same reason as I did.

Comment: In passport.authenticaticate user is coming false and info as missing credentials. can you know the mistake. please refer my question for explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898027/passport-js-local-strategy-custom-callback-showing-user-as-false-and-info-as-mi

Comment: @OE1, Thank you. You saved me.

Comment: Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically. This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which req.login() can be invoked to automatically log in the newly registered user.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked. So basically, whenever we are doing the authentication using Passport manually by passing a Callback, we have to explicitly Login the User and Passport won't do it automatically for us.

Answer (score 3):

There's a kink in passport.js that nobody really mentions but I found out. This is why you can create an account or sign in and it authenticates fine at first but later on you find out `req.user` is `undefined` or `req.isAuthenticated()` is `false` throughout the app.

**After authenticating, passport.js requires you to reroute/redirect.** That's how passport initializes the actual session.

```
  signIn(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
      if (!req.user) {
        console.log("User not found!");
      } else {
        res.redirect("/")
        console.log("signed in")
      }
    })
  }
```

If you don't reroute after authenticating, it won't even start your session as a `req.user` and `req.isAuthenticated()` will be false.

My app is a React and Node app but this is true for both Node apps and React/Node apps.

Comment: this is an intriguing answer.  Is this requirement documented anywhere?  it doesn't add up to me!  I've actually tried the res.redirect("/") in my code and it fails in the browser (it doesn't like the response)

Comment: can you provide the source of info in which you found out that a redirect is necessary.  i feel like the passport docs isnt the best :(

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem, could not find any solution on the web but i figured it out.

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
secret: "This is the secret line",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

express-session requirement and use should be before any other use. Try this i am sure this would work, worked for me!!

Comment: possibly duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111571/passports-req-isauthenticated-always-returning-false-even-when-i-hardcode-done

Answer (score 1):

I know its late, but I face this issue with FB login strategy. It was working fine, until suddenly it stopped working and that too just in Safari. I broke my head around all of the above solutions and nothing seemed to work. Finally chrome web console gave away a clue, wherein it still worked on chrome, then. The warning was this:

*A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at `http://www.facebook.com/` was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.*

Only then i realized that i shouldn't set Samesite: true in the express session as it will not set the facebook cookie for login. After days of hacking, I fixed this issue by changing the samesite to "none".

Hope it helps someone, who encounters this issue in the future.

Comment: It helped me! Thanks. I fixed my https site not having cross site req authentication with this. My code here: https://github.com/vcvcchaturvedi/job-helper-be/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Also used withCredentials: true in client side invocation of requests!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue , and the problem was Cookies blocked by default on the browser i uses . To fix it i add my app URL to the allowed sides for use cookies .

Answer (score 1):

For me, I did what all the answers said, but it wouldn't log in, at least most of the time. However, it was strange because if I throttled my network to 3G in Chrome developer tools, the login did work. My problem was that the session was not saving. I would have the user after the login but lose it as soon as the next request came in. My solution was to use the `req.session.save` callback (as suggested [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/482#issuecomment-230594566)) AND the `req.logIn()` callback:

```js
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        failureFlash: true,
        //failureRedirect: /login", // these don't work!
        //successRedirect: "/home", // because they redict too fast
    }, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err !== null || user === false) {
            req.session.save(() => {
                // failureRedirectin the callback here
                res.redirect("/login");
            });
        } else {
            req.logIn(user, err => {
                // save session before redirecting!
                req.session.save(() => {
                    // successRedirectin the callback here
                    res.redirect("/home");
                });
            });
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

The race conditions were fixed by waiting until the passport session was saved before allowing the next request through the redirect.

Not sure if this is just for the local strategy. Using express-session.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by fixing my *passport.deserializeUser*. I'm using mongo native and since most of the examples use Mongoose i fell in to the _id trap once again.

So remember to make the _id a mongo ObjectID when reading the user in deserializeUser

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    const collection = db.get().collection('users')
    const userId = new mongo.ObjectID(user);
    collection.findOne({_id : userId}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) done(err, null);
        done(null, user);
    });
});
```

My query was not finding the user since I did not make the id an ObjectID, and there was no errors indicated anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing same problem, but @PVThomas gives me solution, as in here in Answers. 
My problem was with `findById()` method in `deserialize()`. I was using `findOne()` in `findById()` and then I replaced it with `find()` and now `req.isAuthenticated()` is working fine. My app wasn't saving `req.session.passport.user`, It was returning **undefined** and then after replacement of `findOne()` with `find()` it's saving user id in `req.session.passport.user`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem even though logging in was happening.
The mistake I did was calling the middleware  isLoggedIn before initializing the passport.
So the sequence in which you write the code is quite important.Please see to it that the sequence is written in the right order.
I had written in the following sequence

```
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret:'short' ,
    resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:false,
  cookie:{secure:false}
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
passport.use(new localstrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (user.password!=password) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
))
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser())
app.use(isLoggedIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in my case, I also faced the same problem, but resolved just by reordering the code as mentioned below:

//--------------------------------

previous code :

```
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: 'somesecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
// using the custom middleware for storing variable in response
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated()
    next()
})
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

//--------------------------------

Refactored code : (which fixed the problem):

```
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: 'somesecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// using the custom middleware for storing variable in response
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated()
    next()
})
```

//--------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @karan525.  However, I made sure to test the portion of my code at different locations on my app page.  Where it finally worked for me was towards the start but after any configuration files.

```
// Session 
app.use(session({
secret: 'not so secret',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
}));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is from the view, either ejs, pug or react. there is no name property in your form group corresponding to the arguments passed to the localstrategy callback function.
This is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem. I fixed it by changing the sequence of function calls.

```
// Call session middleware first
expressApp.use(session(....blah))

// Then initialize passport
expressApp.use(passport.initialize());
expressApp.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I would like to share my mistake here.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }    
  })
```

If you use this code make sure to change the code as follows,

```
cookie:{ secure :false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the secure key in the cookie to false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you wrap your routes like so:

```
module.exports = function(){

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
 res.send('stuff');
  }

}
```

You have to pass "app and passport" to your routes like so:

```
module.exports = function(app,passport){

//routes n stuff

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your example.