# My user gets authenticated in passport to login, but in one of my route files it says that the logged in user is not authenticated

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('danger', 'You must log in');
    } else {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {users: req.user});
    }
})

// Store data for the user from the profile page
router.post("/", function(req, res) {  
})


module.exports = router;

})
```

Comment: See [passport's req.isAuthenticated always returning false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111571/passports-req-isauthenticated-always-returning-false-even-when-i-hardcode-done) and read the comments on the accepted answer too.

Comment: Thank you! That link helped.