# req.isAuthenticated() in express and passport-local returns false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, passport.js, passport-local

I hope someone can shed some light on my situation. The **req.isAuthenticated()** always returns false, after being called in an app.router endpoint(**running in port 3001**), via fetch API. It appears, the connect.sid was not successfully passed on req arg when I do **req.isAuthenticated()**

On the other hand, **my react dev server runs on port 3000**

Here is my current setup.

Login Route, which authenticates username and password, and returns connect.sid via cookie value.

```
const express           = require('express')
const router            = express.Router()
const passport          = require('passport')
...
router.post( '/authenticate', passport.authenticate('local'), ( req, res, next ) => {
    res.status( 200 ).json({
        'response': 'Welcome User',
        'redirect' : '/dashboard'
    })
})
...
module.exports = router
```

At this point, my Users Route should be able to access the protected route. which simply returns all users on the database.

```
const express           = require('express')
const router            = express.Router()
const SimpleCmsUsers    = require('../models/Users.models.js')
const authPassportLocal = require('../passport/auth.PassportLocal.js') 
...
router.get( '/', authPassportLocal ,( req, res, next ) => {
    console.log( req.headers )
    console.log( req.body )

    SimpleCmsUsers
    .find({})
    .then(( users ) => {
        return res.status( 200 ).json( users )
    })
    .catch(( error ) => {
        return res.status( 403 ).json( error )
    })
})
...
module.exports = router
```

My **auth.PassportLocal.js** which checks the value of **req.isAuthenticated()**

```
const authPassportLocal = ( req, res, next ) => {
    console.log( req.headers ) // I do not see session has been passed on my request
    console.log( req.body )    // empty
    console.log('isAuthenticated', req.isAuthenticated() ) // log if isAuthenticated returns true. 
    if ( req.isAuthenticated() ) {
         return next()
    }
    return res.redirect('/dashboard/login/index')
}
....
module.exports = authPassportLocal
```

Now, when I call **/dashboard/users** the via fetch API

```
fetch( '/dashboard/users', {
    headers :{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
})
.then(( response ) => response.json())
.then(( users ) => console.log( users ))
.catch(( error ) => console.log( error ))
```

this returns **isAuthenticated false**, I tried to view the headers received from, **/dashboard/users**, however, I do not see any cookies passed on my request.

Here is my **index.js**

```
const express           = require('express')
const session           = require('express-session')
const flash             = require('express-flash')
const cors              = require('cors')
const passport          = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy     = require('passport-local').Strategy
const Users             = require('./routes/Users.routes.js')
const Login             = require('./routes/Login.routes')
const SimpleCmsUsers    = require('./models/Users.models.js')
const app               = express()

app.use( express.json() )
app.use( express.urlencoded({ extended: true }) )
app.use( cors({
     origin: ['http://localhost:3001', 'http://localhost:3000'],
     credentials: true
}))
app.use( flash() )
app.use( session({
    secret: 'EUE7J3lUE01xhmCGQt04S8PbsMpUE5JDcQj0fyS0cy73PQVDLM',       
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.use( passport.initialize() )
app.use( passport.session() )

passport.use( new LocalStrategy(
    {
        // passport-local option here ...
    },
    ( username, password, done ) => {
        try {
            SimpleCmsUsers.find({ user_username : username, user_password : password }, function ( err, docs ) {
                if ( !docs.length ) {
                    return done( null, false, { message: "User not found!" } )
                }
                return done( null, username )
            })
        }
        catch( error ) {
            return done( null, false, { message: error } )
        }
    }
))
passport.serializeUser(function( user, done ) {
    done( null, user );
})
passport.deserializeUser(function( user, done ) {
    done( null, user );
})

app.use('/dashboard/users', Users)
app.use('/dashboard/login', Login)

app.listen( PORT, () => console.log("Express JS is on port " + PORT) )
```

What bothers me most, these current setup works on Postman without this type of challenge.

In my fetch API request (http://localhost:3001/dashboard/users'):

```
url /
headers {
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36',
  dnt: '1',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  accept: '*/*',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/users',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fil;q=0.8',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AJEG3MNSqtl33KqmHR2DhGlslnlkMKIPT.xsI%2F%2B82%2F1x8zTlq%2BkRN6aJVVbrauH8qv8jDhsrvNlbY'
}
body {}
user undefined
session Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
isAuthenticated false
```

In Postman (http://localhost:3001/dashboard/users'):

```
url /
headers {
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.22.0',
  accept: '*/*',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '443a064e-7909-43db-9783-79a6ba8bd4c5',
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AsvbYi_oxm4yqXTTa7S-N-3qAT6BdW5-u.QYFAXzayArpV1%2BDbjnwJ3fMMjpLzkM%2Fr9kIUCUCYscY',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
}
body {}
user username
session Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  passport: { user: 'username' }
}
isAuthenticated true
```

It just I can not see what went wrong, why fetch API cannot pass the cookie value from connect.sid

Any help or guide where to isolate this behavior better are highly appreciated.

TA

**Update**

```
npm run start // for react dev server running in port 3000
nodemon api/v1/index.js // for express api running in port 3001
```

Tried these threads below, however, I do not see any progress on my end:

[passport's req.isAuthenticated always returning false, even when I hardcode done(null, true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111571/passports-req-isauthenticated-always-returning-false-even-when-i-hardcode-done)

[Basics of Passport Session (expressjs)-why do we need to serialize and deserialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381931/basics-of-passport-session-expressjs-why-do-we-need-to-serialize-and-deseriali)

Comment: You've to set express session domain param to be with port :3000 (frontend's port) see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Only question is that how cookies being set.

Since You're backend runs at **:3001** cookies being set as for host: **localhost:3001**.

Read this issue: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/403

solution is to make session middleware to set cookie by different host

```
app.use( session({
    secret: 'EUE7J3lUE01xhmCGQt04S8PbsMpUE5JDcQj0fyS0cy73PQVDLM',       
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {domain: 'localhost:3000'}
}))
```