# express session is not work in mongo and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**index.js**

```
var store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri:
    "mongodb+srv://...........................?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  collection: "........."
});
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 3600000
    },
    store: store
  })
);
```

**account.ts**

```
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  if (email == "email@gmail.com" && password == "1234") {
    console.log("work is true");
    req.session.isAuthenticated = "true";
  }
};
```

**Problem:**
Post added successfully. But the session is not working. There is no error message. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use this config in `index.js` file, it work for me

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-database', {
    useMongoClient: true
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'my-secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
       maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 // 1 hour
    }
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: db })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
// persistent login sessions 
app.use(passport.session());
```

and you should make middle ware with `passport` and work with it. and read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381931/basics-of-passport-session-expressjs-why-do-we-need-to-serialize-and-deseriali)