req.isAuthenticated() doesn't work as it should
I am trying to implement passport. What i am trying to achive is only logged in users will be able to access /create route and create new posts.
I imported necessary libraries.
import passport from "passport";
import localStrategy from "passport-local";
import session from "express-session";
import connectPgSimple from 'connect-pg-simple';


I implement passpor logic.
 passport.use(new localStrategy(async function verify(username, password, cb) {
    try {
      const result = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM loginDetail WHERE username = $1`, [username]);
      if (result.rows.length === 0) {
        return cb(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username or password" });
      }
      const row = result.rows[0];
      bcrypt.compare(password, row.password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Error comparing passwords:", err);
          return cb(null, false, { message: "Failed to compare passwords" });
        } else if (result) {
          // Passwords match, user is authorized
          return cb(null, row);
        } else {
          // Passwords don't match, render login page with error message
          return cb(null, false, { message: "Invalid credentials. Please try again." });
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }
  }));

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'keyboard cat',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { secure: true }
    })
  ); 
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    cb(null, user.id);
  });
  
  // passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  //   // Retrieve user from the database based on the provided ID
  //   // Example assuming you have a `User` model:
  //   db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id], function(err, result) {
  //     if (err) { return cb(err); }
  //     cb(null, user);
  //   });
  // });
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM loginDetail WHERE id = $1', [id], function(err, result) {
      if(err)
        return done(err, user);
      if(result.rows.length > 0){
        const user = result.rows[0];
        done(null, user)
      }else{done(null, false)}
    });
  });
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

app.post("/login",passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login',successRedirect:"/" }), async (req, res) => {
  
});

I create ensureAuthenticated to make sure only loggedin users will be able to access /create route.
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    // If the user is authenticated, allow the request to proceed
    return next();
  } else {
    // If the user is not authenticated, redirect to the login page
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
}

app.get("/create",ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("create.ejs");
});

app.post("/create",ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  
    const result = await db.query("SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM posts");
    const maxId = result.rows[0].max_id || 0; // If no posts exist, set maxId to 0

    // Increment the maximum ID by one to generate a new unique ID
    const newId = maxId + 1;
    const post = {
      id: newId,
      author: req.body.author,
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
    };

    const postPush = await db.query(
      "INSERT INTO posts (id,author,title,content) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING *;",
      [post.id, post.author, post.title, post.content]
    );

  
});

I implemented passport logic and created function ensureAuthenticated to allow only loggedin users to access and create post. I successfully login and be redirected to /.

I fixed the problem found it on stackoverflow "My problem was that i set cookie.secure to true even if data was not over https.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111571/passports-req-isauthenticated-always-returning-false-even-when-i-hardcode-done

app.use(require('express-session')({
secret: process.env.sessionSecret,
cookie: {
maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
},
store: store,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
cookie: { secure: false } // Remember to set this })); Remember to set cookies to false if you're not using https
cookie: { secure: false } // Set to false Also if you do believe you
have https remember to trust the proxy
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy"

