# Using sails LocalStrategy to get a simple auth

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cookies, sails.js, restful-authentication

I'm developing a rest server with a login function and other api (all verified against authentication and all are cors enabled).

So I've myhost/api/login (i can pass email and password in post)

On the other side I've some clients, in my case wrote angular, and I would like they can use that api to get logged in.

For example look at this client code:

```
(function() {
angular.module('controller.auth', [])
.controller("authController", ['$q','$scope', '$interval', '$http', '$cookies', function( $q, $scope, $interval,$http, $cookies) {

    console.log('auth');
    $scope.whoami = false;
    $scope.login = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://api.marketplace.local:1337/login',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {email: 'myemail@email.com', password: 'password'}
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.logged = true;
        }, function(res) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(res);
        });
    }

    $scope.me = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://api.marketplace.local:1337/api/user/me',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.me = res.data;
        }, function(res) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(res);
        });
    }

}])
})();
```

this is the html:

```
<div ng-controller="authController">
<div ng-click="login()" style="cursor: pointer">LOGIN</div>
<div ng-show="logged" ng-click="me()" style="cursor: pointer">WHOAMI</div>
<div ng-show="whoami">Hi, I'm {{whoami.email}}</div>
</div>
```

When I click on LOGIN, login is succesfull, but when I click on WHOAMI I've a 403.

So, how can I use the login function to get authenticated for the next call?

I mean, I thought to get the cookie from the response after login and set it for the next call, but also if I saw the cookie from firebug I can't access from $http().then().

Another idea is to send the sessionId in the login response, but I can't figure out how to use it.

I need some advice where to look.

Comment: Here the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602804/nodejs-passport-isauthenticated-returning-false-even-after-login